# i could not install dlib

Tags: python, installation, dlib

I am trying to install `dlib` in anaconda(3.7) and this is what i have got:

````
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Alaa\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Alaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppcbhbjq\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppcbhbjq\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-n0ux30e_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Alaa\anaconda3\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: pip install --upgrade setuptools

Answer (score 0):

try "pip install dlib" in the terminal